# React context provider component's children not re-render?

Tags: reactjs, react-context

When I try to modularize react context in my app for more re-useable,
I find that the rendering behavior is different, which confuses me.

So my question is: Why case1 won't print "inner2", but case2 will?

Below it's my code:

[codesandbox-demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/boring-monad-edblbt?file=/src/App.js)

I thought the situation should be the same for both, but not.

**[UPDATE] Tue Dec 13 2022 12:10:56 GMT+0800**

Sorry, my description is not precise enough. What I mean is printing inner2 in the console

Comment: I just tried your codesandbox and both Case1 and Case2 print `inner2`

Comment: Yep, looks like both Components work the same https://codesandbox.io/s/quizzical-river-nriiev?file=/src/index.js

Comment: Sorry, my description is not precise enough. What I mean is printing inner2 in the console